# Make an object for an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

I am building a react-native / typescript project and I run into this problem:

I have a list of objects that I fetch from an API, and it looks something like this:

```
[{ qwe1: 'Bob', qwe2: 18 },
{ qwe1: 'James', qwe2: 19 }]
```

But I don't want to have those keys names for this object (qwe1, qwe2),
and I also don't want to run throw all the objects and change all the keys.

So I thought to make an object that will hold all the keys of the original object but give nice access for better names for them, it's look something like that :

```
{
name: 'qwe1',
age: 'qwe2'
}
```

and then when I want to access the user's name for example I will do this:

`myObject[objectKeyNames.name]`

I also made a type for the object that look like this:

`{qwe1: string; qwe2: number;}`

But then an error was showed up saing that:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '<the name of the type>'`

I am really new to typescript and I don't really get this, I would be most grateful for your support.

**Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `objectKeyNames` object to specifically reference the keys from the data object.

For example

```ts
interface ApiResult {
  qwe1: string;
  qwe2: number;
}

const objectKeyNames: {[key: string]: keyof ApiResult} = {
  name: "qwe1",
  age: "qwe2"
};

// ---

const myObject: ApiResult = {
  qwe1: "Bob",
  qwe2: 18
};

console.log(myObject[objectKeyNames.name]);
```

Now Typescript knows that any key in `objectKeyNames` will reference a valid property name from the API result.

---

As an aside, it's usually trivial to re-map one data format to another

```ts
const niceObjects = results.map(({ qwe1, qwe2 }) => ({
  name: qwe1,
  age: qwe2,
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of TypeScript, as opposed to JavaScript, is type safety. In ordinary JavaScript, `person.lastMane` will silently give you `undefined`; TypeScript compiler will give you a compile-time warning that people don't have last manes. However, when you do `person[attribute]`, where `attribute` is a string whose value cannot be known at compile-time, TypeScript must wash hands of it. It can't know if `attribute` will be `"lastName"`, or if it will end up as `"lastMane"`. So it goes "I don't know about this, this is on you."

In order to satisfy TypeScript, one thing you can do is have a lookup of accessors instead of a lookup of attribute names, so that you never need to dynamically look up an attribute by a string. Something like this:

```
interface APIPerson {
  qwe1: string;
  qwe2: number;
}

const personAccessors = {
  "name": (apiPerson: APIPerson) => apiPerson.qwe1,
  "age": (apiPerson: APIPerson) => apiPerson.qwe2,
};

const apiPerson: APIPerson = {
  qwe1: "John",
  qwe2: 25,
}

const personName = personAccessors.name(apiPerson);
console.log(personName);
```

EDIT: ...but Phil's solution is smarter :) I leave this up primarily because of the explanation of why you are getting the error.